# Explanation: System of quadratic equations, solved incorrectly through algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm quite young and haven't used this site before, so I apologise if I'm not laying things out correctly or any other problem really (tips would be appreciated). Regardless, here's something I'm quite confused about.

Problem:

$x^2 + xy = 20$

$y^2 + xy = 30$

Solve: $xy$

The solution to this problem is xy=12. However, I found a way where I got the answer of ±12. It is very easy to see why -12 is impossible, but the algebra that I wrote down still makes sense. If possible, can someone please explain where I went wrong.

Algebraic "proof" of ±12:

Adding the two equations gives:

$x^2 + 2xy + y^2 = 50$

$(x+y)^2 = 50$

$x+y = ±5√2$

Since:

$x^2 +xy = 20  =>  x(x+y) = 20  =>  x(±5√2)$

then

$x = 20/(±5√2) = ±2√2$

following the same logic,

$y = ±3√2 $

So surely, $xy = ±6 * 2 = ±12 $?

It obviously doesn't, and proving that it doesn't is easy - but where did I go wrong with the algebra above? Again, sorry if I didn't set things out correctly I don't know LaTeX or anything like that.

Comment: Note that $(x+y)^2=30$ not 50 and $y^2+xy = 20$ not $x^2+xy = 20$. Regardless, you will find that when y is positive, so is x and when y is negative, so is x. Then the product is always positive.

Comment: If $xy=12$, then $x^2=10-12=-2$ which is impossible in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x =2\sqrt{2}$ this mandates $y=3\sqrt{2}$ in the way you have solved it, because $x+y$ must equal $+5\sqrt{2}$ or $-5\sqrt{2}$.

Therefore the product xy is either $2\sqrt{2} \times 3\sqrt{2}$ OR $-2\sqrt{2} \times -3\sqrt2$ which are both 12.

Apart from adding 20 and 10 to get 50, your algebra was absolutely fine. It's just that small nuance that you were forgetting ($x+y=\pm5\sqrt{2}$ is a constraint on your solutions).